# Can I use the parallel version of for loop and apply family together?

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, apply, doparallel

I met one problem recently when I am doing my research: at first, I defined a function `myfunction` which contains two for loops in it and then I use `lapply(datalist, myfunction)`, but the processing is too slow.

Then I learned two parallel packages 'foreach' and 'parallel' to do parallel computation. So I changed both processes to their parallel versions.

BUT I found that when I run my code, it seems that the foreach in my function doesn't work.

```
myfunction <- function{data} {

   df  <- foreach (i = 1:200, .combine = "rbind") %:% 
    foreach(j = 1:200, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {

      *****
      process
      *****
    }

  data <- df[1,1]
  return(data)
}

system.time({

  cl <- detectCores()
  cl <- makeCluster(cl)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  mat <- t(parSapply(cl, list, myfuntion))

  stopCluster(cl)

})
```

I feel like it's due to the `parSapply` occupied the whole cores so `foreach` don't have additional cores to compute. Is there any good idea to fix it? Basically I want to achieve both two processes running in their parallel versions.

Another problem is: suppose we can only choose one process to do the parallel computation, which one should I choose? The for loop or apply family?

Much appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Comment: @JérômeRichard when the `list` only contains one dataset, then I run the same code. Ideally speaking, I wish to call all my cores to compute but it shows that only approximate 10-15% of cpu is used. In another word, the `foreach` in my denied function does NOT work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I feel like it's due to the parSapply occupied the whole cores so foreach don't have additional cores to compute. Is there any good idea to fix it? Basically I want to achieve both two processes running in their parallel versions.

Nah, that's not a good idea. You're basically trying to over-parallelize here (but that does actually happen in your code as explained below).

> Another problem is: suppose we can only choose one process to do the parallel computation, which one should I choose? The for loop or apply family?

There is no one right answer to that.  I recommend that you profile your `*** process ***` code to figure out how much it gains from parallelization.

So, I found your `parSapply(cl, ...)` on top a `foreach() %dopar% { ... }` using the same cluster `cl` interesting.  First time I've seen this asked/proposed in that way.  You don't want to do this for sure but the question/attempt is not crazy.  Your intuition that all workers would be occupied when `foreach() %dopar% { ... }` attempts to use them is partly correct.  However, what is really happening is also that the `foreach() %dopar% { ... }` statement is evaluated in the **workers** not the main R session where the cluster `cl` was defined.  On the workers, there are no foreach adaptors registered, so those calls will default to sequential processing (== `foreach::registerDoSEQ()`).  To achieve nested parallelization, you'd had to set up and register a cluster within each worker, e.g. inside the `myfunction()` function.

As the author of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework, I'd like to propose you make use of that. It'll protect you against the above mistakes and it will not over-parallel either (you can do it if you really really want to do it).   Here is how I would rewrite your code example:

```
library(foreach) ## foreach() and %dopar%

myfunction <- function{data} {
   df  <- foreach(i = 1:200, .combine = "rbind") %:% 
    foreach(j = 1:200, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
      *****
      process
      *****
    }

  data <- df[1,1]
  return(data)
}


## Tell foreach to parallelize via the future framework
doFuture::registerDoFuture()

## Have the future framework parallelize using a cluster of
## local workers (similar to makeCluster(detectCores()))
library(future)
plan(multisession)

library(future.apply) ## future_sapply()

system.time({
  mat <- t(future_sapply(list, myfuntion))
})
```

Now, what is important to understand is that the outer `future_sapply()` parallelization will operate on the 'multisession' cluster.  When you get to the inner `foreach() %dopar% { ... }` parallelization, all that foreach sees is a sequential worker so that inner layer will be processed in parallel.  This is what I mean that the future framework will automatically protect you from over-parallelization.

If you'd like to have the inner layer parallelize on a 'multisession' cluster and the outer to be sequential, you can set that up as:

```
plan(list(sequential, multisession))
```

If you really want to do nested parallelization, say, two outer-level workers and 4 inner-level workers, you can use:

```
plan(list(tweak(multisession, workers = 2), tweak(multisession, workers = 4))
```

This will run 2*4 = 8 parallel R processes at the same time.

What is more useful is when you have multiple machines available, then you can use those for the outer level and then use a multisession cluster on each of them.  Something like:

```
plan(list(tweak(cluster, workers = c("machine1", "machine2")), multisession))
```

You can read more about this in [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) vignettes.

Comment: I think I would try the nested parallelization you mentioned in your reply later. Btw, the code to combine multiple machines is very nice. Thanks :D